# Sort structure according another array

Tags: arrays, matlab, sorting, structure

I have structure A which is to be sorted according to ascending order of array c.

```
A.a=[2 3 1]
A.b=[5 3 6]
c=[4 2 1]
[c1 c2]=sort(c)
A=A(c2)  % It is not working
```

Index exceeds matrix dimension error is shown.

Comment: Do you want to sort the struct `A` or the arrays `A.a` and `A.b`? It seems to me you intend to do the latter.

Comment: The struct A is to be sorted

Comment: So you want to change the order of the members of the struct? As I see it, `A` is an array with one element, `A(1)`. `A(2)` doesn't exist. What is there to sort? However, `A.a` is a vector, and you can reorder its elements with `A.a(c2)`. Are you sure that that is not what you need?

Comment: Strct A consists of vector a and b. By ordering if struct A, I mean all its vectors are to be sorted. In this case there are two vectors. It may contain more number of vectors, so how it could be done with simple coding.

Comment: See? That's a whole different question. "Sort the struct" vs "sort all the vectors in the struct". I'm not trying to be anal about language, I'm trying to show you that accurately presenting your question is an important part of getting it answered.

Comment: You've got a good answer now, but I suggest you edit your question to correctly express the question, then accept tuntap's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want to use `structfun`

```
A.a = [2 3 1]
A.b = [5 3 6]
c = [4 2 1]
[~, c2] = sort(c)
A = structfun(@(x) x(c2), A, 'UniformOutput', false)
```

But it seems that all of your vectors are of the same length. Why not store them as rows in a matrix instead of a struct?

```
A = [2 3 1; 5 3 6]
c = [4 2 1]
[~, c2] = sort(c)
A = A(:, c2)
```

Comment: structfun is what I was expecting at. Thanks, for suggesting this function.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you just need to change the format of `A`, this works

```
A(1).a = 2; A(1).b = 5;
A(2).a = 3; A(2).b = 3;
A(3).a = 1; A(3).b = 6;
c=[4 2 1];
[c1 c2]=sort(c);
A = A(c2);
```

If you don't want to change the structure of A (but then I guess the whole exercise doesn't make sense at all), then you need to sort each field seperately

```
A.a = A.a(c2);
A.b = A.b(c2);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. This is easy approach when no. of arrays are few. Structfun is more appropriate.